# How can I generate an internal structure for an object in matlab using hyperbolic 3D tessellation algorithm?

Tags: matlab

I need some help to finish the following task:

a) Consider the problem of generating an internal structure (filling) for an object
defined in an .off file using hyperbolic 3D tessellation algorithm.
b) Save the filled object in .OFF format.

I managed so far to write a code that generates in matlab an object defined in .off file. I think I'm able to save the filled object back in .off format (question b) but I've no idea how to generate that internal structure. Couldn't find anything about what is hyperbolic 3D tessellation algorithm either. Any advice about how to solve this will be highly appreciated.